# Should I use protocol or streams in asyncio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, coroutine, python-asyncio

I'm very new to `asyncio` and was wondering which API is better than the other in terms of better practice, protocol or streams?

To me, `protocol(callback based API)` seems easier to work with since there are already `connection_made` and `data_received` methods provided to you.  With `streams(coroutine based API)` you have to manage connections and read data yourself, but I feel like it utilizes concept of `coroutine` more, which seems a good thing to me.

this is how i listen to incoming data, feels awkward to me. I can also use `readeexactly` but sometimes it raises `IncompleteReadError`.

```
message_body = b''
message_length = SOME_NUMBER
while True:
    while len(message_body) < message_length:
        try:
            message_body_chunk = await reader.read(message_length - len(message_body))
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(e)
            return
            if not message_body_chunk:
                return
            message_body += message_body_chunk
```

Answer (score 6):

The [stream objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#streams-coroutine-based-api) are higher level and provide many useful methods:

- Several ways to read data: [reader.read, readline, readuntil, readexactly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamReader.read)
- Check if EOF has been reached: [reader.ateof](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamReader.at_eof)
- Control write flow: [writer.drain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamWriter.drain)

Like any abstraction, this comes at a cost: coroutine are a bit less reactive than callbacks. For instance `reader.read()` involves at least two event loop callbacks:

- When some data is received, a callback is triggered and `reader.feed_data` is called.
- Then `feed_data` triggers another callback that restores the execution of `reader.read()`.

Comment: Also, an important point to note is that asyncio does not ensure that data_received in Protocol is always called with entire data. You may need to do your own buffer-management if the amount of data is large, or increase the buffer limit.

Comment: @Zack This doesn't have much to do with asyncio, but rather TCP itself. TCP is [stream oriented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17446839/2846140), so there is no such thing as the "entire data". It's up to the application layer to define a protocol with its own concept of packet (e.g. fixed length, ending with a specific separator, etc.). This is why the asyncio stream reader provides the readuntil and readexactly helpers.